# Pulling a URL by only using the first few digits

Tags: php, mysql, url, hyperlink

What I need to do is have  my page create a link to .pdf files. The only consistency and unique value in the file name is at the beginning.  Each file name has a unique number.  For instance file: "501599-Fresno_Catalog_version2"  On my page the catalog number "501599" is stored in the database, but not the entire file name.  This is because others access the files directly and may change part of the name to "version3", but they wont change the catalog number.  How can I create a dynamic link that will open this file by only providing the catalog number to the url?  Is this possible?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you mean "How can I have a long URL like /catalog/501599-Fresno_Catalog_version2 that links to record 501599?"

Comment: Please put your code, i can't understand your goal clearly

Comment: I do not have any code yet.  Trying to figure out how to code it.  I have a file located at: "http://mysite.com/501599-Fresno_Catalog_version2.pdf"  I want to be able to pull that file (through a URL/link) by only providing the url/link the "501599".  Can I reach out with a url like "http://mysite.com/501599" and have it find and open the file that has a complete name of "501599-Fresno_Catalog_version2.pdf"...  but I cant supply my url/link with the entire name, only the "501599".  This is also from one site to another, so the file is not on the same server as the website with the url/link.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to locate the whole PDF file using just the unique file number.

You can use the PHP `glob()` function:

```
$pdf_files = glob('./path/to/pdfs/501599*.pdf');
```

or (using variables):

```
$path_to_pdfs = './path/to/pdfs/'; // change to your path
$file_number = 501599; // change to set this from the database

// get the array of pdf files matching
$pdf_files = glob($path_to_images . $file_number . '*.pdf');

// for debug, you can output the array like this:
print_r($pdf_files);

// if there's only one file every time, you can get it with $pdf_files[0]
```

`glob` returns an array of all pathnames matching the search string, which in this case is your path/to/images + anything (hence the wildcard *) + the PDF extension.

So, when you retrieve the unique file number from the database, you can run `glob()` with the path to the files and unique file number adapted from my code above, and then do what you need with the file.

Here's the glob() documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: Thanks!  Ill check that out.  Appreciate the feedback from both Anton and njk

Comment: Thanks.  I read about glob.  Unfortunately this will not work for me because the file is located on a different server.

Comment: Is there anything like glob that will work with files on another server.  basically using a url to the other server, unlike glob you have to use a relative path on the same server.?

Comment: Not that I know of, because commands like that can't be run remotely, but it depends on permissions. What type of access do you have to this remote server?

Comment: just web, its a Sharepoint server so its secure.  I just looked at a bunch of sites and information.  The consensus seems to be that its not possible to do on remote files.  Unless I had FTP access(which I dont)..  I think the alternatives would be A. convince them to move the files to the same server as the website.  B. Make the files names on the remote server match exactly what I have in my database.   thanks for all your help.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you need? Either will work as long as there is a hypen in the filename.

```
$filename = '501599-Fresno_Catalog_version2';
$catalog_number = substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, '-'));
echo $catalog_number;
```

Or

```
$filename = '501599-Fresno_Catalog_version2';
$pieces = explode('-', $filename);
echo $pieces[0];
```

**Result**

```
501599
```

You would then use that piece to form your URL.

Comment: Thanks! Ill check that out. Appreciate the feedback from both Anton and njk